# Package a .exe file with in a msi file

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-installer, installation

Any pointers to package a `.exe` file within a `.msi` file ?

When I click the `.msi` file it should execute the `.exe` file (which is inturn packaged within the `.msi` file).

Would love to do this in a programmatical way. Or any ideas to do the same in non-programmatic ways are also welcome :)

Comment: You can package .exe file within another .exe file, or package .msi within .exe

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: You are right. I am looking out for a `how to do it` kind of doc. Do you a know some sites or docs I can refer to

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate program called `"self_extracting.exe"`, copy the installation file in to resource section of self_extracting file.

When you run `"self_extracting.exe"`, it will extract `"main.msi"` from its own resource and copy it to hard disk. `"self_extracting.exe"` will then execute `"main.msi"` from hard disk.

This is an example in c#
[Self-extracting Installer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339768/Flexible-Self-Extracting-Application-in-Csharp-Pro)

Above example is perhaps over complicated. Here is a simple example to do this with WinAPI:

Create C++ Win32 project.

Add this line to *.rc file:

```
1 RCDATA "path_on_my_computer.msi"
```

When you build the project, *.msi file will be written to resource section. If *.msi file changes, compile the resource file again.

You have one *.cpp file as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"//if using precompiled headers
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, wchar_t*, int)
{
    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(0, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), RT_RCDATA);
    if (!hrsrc) return 0;

    HANDLE hglob = LoadResource(0, hrsrc);
    if (!hglob) return 0;

    unsigned int size = SizeofResource(0, hrsrc);
    if (size <= 0) return 0;

    void *ptr = LockResource(hglob);

    wchar_t* setup_file = L"path_on_user_computer.msi";
    std::ofstream f(setup_file, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    f.write((char*)ptr, size);
    f.close();

    ShellExecute(0, 0, setup_file, 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    return 0;
}
```

In release mode, go to "Project Properties" -> "Code generation" -> "Run time library", and select "Multi-threaded (/MT)" so the *.exe file can run without dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily with Advanced Installer, there is a tutorial [convert EXE to MSI](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-convert-exe-to-msi.html) which actually creates an MSI wrapper over you EXE.

**No coding** is required.

You can place multiple EXE installers in this wrapper, to chain their execution. Also, for each EXE you can pass command line switches to make their installation silent (if the EXE supports such switches), thus you can obtain an MSI that supports full automatization to install you EXEs.